# How to add .gif in splash screen using cordova in quasar?

Tags: cordova, progressive-web-apps, splash-screen, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm building a PWA using quasar. I found a way to create a splash screen using .png in their documentation (using icongenie). However, I'd like to use .gif rather than .png. I've replaced the png files in config.xml. It doesn't work. It only gives me a blank screen and then my first page eventually shows after a couple of seconds. Is there some plugins or a way that I can use to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Quasar so I'm going to answer for pure Cordova. GIF are not supported by the Splashscreen plugin. But if you want animations, you should consider using [lottie](https://lottiefiles.com/) animations and [lottie splashscreen](https://github.com/timbru31/cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen)